# PHP order by clicks in WHILE

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop

I am trying to order in while from higger count of clicks to the lower and I am a bit of lost so I decided to ask the qustion here.

My code :

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT `country` FROM `entries` ORDER by `id` ASC");
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $clicks = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `entries` WHERE `country` LIKE '{$row['country']}'")->rowCount();
        $conversations = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `conversations` WHERE `country` LIKE '{$row['country']}' AND `link_id` = '{$id}'")->rowCount();
    }
```

I want the foreach give me results from highest count of `$clicks` to the lowest.

Any ideas what can I do ?

Comment: What `foreach`? You mean the `while` loop?

Comment: first of all, you must use `$clicks[]` instead of `$click` and then you will be able to use `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this query entirely in SQL with something like this (depending on SQL dialect):

```
$countries = $db->query("SELECT `country`, count(1) AS clicks FROM `entries` GROUP BY `country` ORDER BY clicks DESC");
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    echo "${country['country']} has ${country['clicks']} clicks. ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put number of `clicks` in an array as below :

```
 $clicks[] = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `entries` WHERE `country` LIKE '{$row['country']}'")->rowCount();
```

then you can simply sort the array by `rsort` php function as below :

```
echo rsort($clicks);
```